# How can I remove a physic node safely in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I add some nodes that move around the screen. at some point, when I press a button (`MenuItemImage`), I need to change layer (not scene). So, I try to remove all moving nodes' `PhysicBody` from the `PhysicWorld` and then, remove nodes themselves. It works usually, but sometimes, I get crash from inside of `PhysicsBody::update` function. at that point, `this` refers moving object `PhysicBody`. and, it seems parent is NULL. But, I try all `PhysicBody` from the World. So, after I remove, they should not be drawn (I guess this is causing the problem)

It is too obvious that there are some concurrency problem. but, I don't want to touch cocos2d-x dispatcher. so, what is the proper way to remove a `PhysicBody` and node from the world.

now, I call `removeFromWorld()` for PhysicBody and `removeChildren` for Cocos2d node. Even, I put some delay between these two operation, I still get crash sometimes.

Comment: post the related/offending code

Comment: removeAllChildren(); would be enough after add some sprite nodes that move around the screen.